# Exception not caught by ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, smarty

In the `onBootstrap` of my Application's Module.php I have registered a function `onErrors` on the EVENT_DISPATCH and EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR events. In any of my models if I throw a custom error, Zend will catch it for me and in the `onErrors` function and I can handle the error (show an error page, return an error message as json, etc). This works fine except when an error is thrown in a function that's being used by Smarty. In that case I do still end up in the `onErrors`, but `McvEvent->exception` is NULL and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Application\Exception\InternalServerErrorException' in
> /........../module/Smarty/src/Smarty/View/Renderer.php:90 Stack trace:
>
> #0 /........../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php(205):
> Smarty\View\Renderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #1 /........../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102):
> Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> #2 [internal function]:
> Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #3 /........../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468):
> call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> #4 /........../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207):
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render.error',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
>
> #5 /.......... in
> /........../module/Smarty/src/Smarty/View/Renderer.php on line 90

What's happening here? Why isn't Zend catching this error for me?

Comment: silly question do you enable smarty module before application module?

Comment: I don't think so. In my application config the Application module is first. I tried moving the Smarty module to the very end, but that doesn't change anything.